# Rollup lines by delimiter count via Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a huge '|' separated file. There are certain lines which have broken into two and shifted to the next line. Given , I know the number of delimiters in each line (say 100) how do I append this to the first half to get the whole correct record.

I have tried the below but it does not work as expected :

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    for line in f:
        lis.append(line)

file_object=open(out_file,'w+')
for x in range(len(lis)):
    line=lis[x]
    delim_count=line.count('|')
    if(delim_count==100):
        file_object.write(line)
    elif(delim_count<100):
        `file_object.write(lis[x]+lis[x+1])        
    x=x+1
file_object.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was almost doing it.

You can have an accumulator that accumulates lines until the number of separators is 100. Note that you have to remove the \n character at the end of the lines.

Here's an improved version of your code:

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as fin:
    with open(out_file, 'w+') as fout:
        accum_line = ''
        for line in fin:
            accum_line += line.rstrip('\n')    # remove '\n' here
            if accum_line.count('|') == 100:
                fout.write(accum_line + '\n')  # add '\n' here
                accum_line = ''
```